# wxPython StopWatch constant display of counting time?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a GUI timer using wxPython.  A Start button is clicked, the timer starts and a label displays the timer counting the seconds up to minutes and maybe to hours.  A Stop button stops the timer.  I don't know how to have the timer constantly displayed in the label.  I tried a while True loop but it seems SetLabel() or Time() wants to display once and is waiting for an end to the loop.

```
import wx

class Timer(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(400, 350))

        self.main()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def main(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 0)

        self.timer = wx.StopWatch()

        self.label = wx.StaticText(panel)
        sizer.Add(self.label, pos=(0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        button_start = wx.Button(panel, label='Start')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, button_start)
        sizer.Add(button_start, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        button_stop = wx.Button(panel, label='Stop')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, button_stop)
        sizer.Add(button_stop, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        sizer.AddGrowableRow(0)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(1)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(2)
        sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnStart(self, event):

        self.timer.Start()
        while True:
            self.label.SetLabel(str(self.timer.Time()))

    def OnStop(self, event):

        self.timer.Pause()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Timer(None, 'Timer')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You never return from OnStart, so the event loop is hung waiting for the event handler to finish.  All event handlers need to return immediately so that other events can be processed.   Use a [wx.Timer](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Timer) handler to update the stopwatch label.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to start from 00:00:00 and count up, right? You should take a look at the LEDNumberCtrl demo in the wxPython demo. The third example in it is very similar to what you're looking for. I think you could get it to work with minimal fiddling.

Comment: The LEDNumberCtrl was mostly what I was looking for, thanks.  It took me a very long time (days) to figure out how to get it to start at 0.  The only thing left is to figure out why the hour starts at 7 (or 19 on 24 hour time).  My LEDNumberCtrl change (the lines with comments): http://pastebin.com/R1FpFTsG